# Is it a threat if top mining player merges?

Tags: bitcoin-core

It just strikes to me that if top 2 bitcoin miners which would own more than 50% mining, merges can they control bitcoin.

In hypothetical scenario if have bad intension can they control the price etx of bitcoin ?

Answer (score 1):

You are speaking of 51% attack or Majority Attack

You can read more about it [in here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Majority_attack)

If they join, yes they can double spend or so.

But they can't change the price though, as that purely depends on the market demand.

Till now, there has been no Majority Attack on BTC, though it has been demonstrated on small altcoins.

Comment: They can control in way that they can hoard bitcoin and dont sell which will raise the demand and hence price. Since they would own the most bitcoins they can control demand right ?

Comment: If this happens, then people will lose trust in BTC. And if trust is lost, then the value will be lost. So, even if they hoard, if no one is there to buy, then artificial demand won't raise the price.

Answer (score 0):

1. If they want spent twice, it will cost a lot of power to do so, so the tx must has huge amounts which be worth to do it. But when you create a transaction with huge amounts, you just wait for more confirmations.
2. But going short the bitcoin market, it would be a tempting reason.